# Why can't I specify a `name` attribute in an ASP.NET MVC form using Html.Helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am playing around with the ASP.NET MVC `Html.Helpers` and I noticed that say for instance:

```
Html.Textbox("test");
```

will render the name attribute to `"name=test"` and the `id` tag will be `"id=test"`

But when I do this:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("go", null, new { @name = "test2", @id = "test2", @class = "test2" })%>
```

`id` will be `"id=test2"` but  `name` will be `"name=go"`

Why does it not get overridden?

I also don't really still understand what the `name` tag actually does. I don't think I ever even used.

P.S

I am aware that "name" and "id" probably don't need to be escaped only "class" does since it is a keyword but I just do it for all of them just so I don't forget to do it or have to even remember if something is a keyword or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name attribute is used when accessing that form element's value on the server side. Like so :

```
string val = Request.Name["go"];
```

As for specifying the name attribute, well that's what the first parameter of the `Html.TextBox` method is there for.

Comment: ah ok can't believe that one flew over my head. The parameter name is called "name" can't believe I could not connect the dots.

So then I guess I should be asking why do they want you to specify the name and not the id?

I am building my own custom html helper should I just do what they just ask them to specify the name?

Comment: Well, I guess it's because the name attribute is an attribute that belongs to the input element(s). Whereas the id attriute is a standard attribute that can be given to any element on page.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it will help the asker but you need to use the correct casing.  To set "name" attribute use:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("go", null, new { Name = "test2", @id = "test2", @class = "test2" })%>
```

Answer (score 1):

ID is unique identifier in DOM tree, name is identifier within form, and it doesn't need to be unique, name is used after submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a "Helper" helping you not to type the name in the 90% of the cases when you create a textbox.

You are free to **not** use them and just type:

```
<input type="textbox" 
       name="theNameIReallyWant" 
       value="<%= model.theNameOfThePropertyInTheModel %>">
```

or better yet, create your own `TextBoxWithCustomName` helper